# How do I access values from excel, where first column is header

Tags: python, excel, pandas, scripting, xlrd

I'm new to accessing data from excel using python. 
I need something like this.

```
[Id:{1,2,3}, Name:{Raj,Rahul,Dave}, Age:{28,29,29}, City:{Delhi,Mumbai,Bengaluru}]
```

I need this kind of data in python list of dictionaries.

this is the excel data:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do it using the `pandas` library :

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx')

df = df.T
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop(df.index[0])

df.to_dict()
```

---

Output :

```
{'Name': {1: 'Raj', 2: 'Rahul', 3: 'Dave'},
 'Age': {1: 28, 2: 29, 3: 29},
 'City': {1: 'Delhi', 2: 'Mumbai', 3: 'Bengaluru'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always preferred that you **insert a person wise record in a single row**. Never the less, you can also do it by csv and defaultdict module in Python.

```
import csv 
from collections import defaultdict

fileName = "./sample.csv"

# initializing the titles and rows list 
fields = []
rows = []

# reading csv file 
with open(fileName, 'r') as csvfile: 
    # creating a csv reader object 
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile) 

    # extracting field names through first row
    record = defaultdict(lambda: None)
    for rows in csvreader:
        row = rows[0].split(" ")
        for i in range(1, len(row)):
            if(record[row[0]]):
                record[row[0]].append(row[i])
            else:
                record[row[0]] = [row[i]]
    print(dict(record))
```